# How to save an array of custom structs to plist swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

I'm trying to save alert data to a plist, it is in the form of an array of the class alertData, all the info i can find points to encoding it, and then putting it in the array, but i'm confused as to what this does? And i also can't figure out how to do it, here's my playground: Any help would be great

The class (i'm trying to save an array of these)

```
public class alertData: NSObject, NSCoding {
//Properties of the timer data - make optionals optional i.e. alert count etc.

var alertCounter: NSTimeInterval?
var alertText: String?
var alertColor: UIColor?
var alertColorIndex: Int?


//initialisation
init(alertCounter: Double, alertText: String, alertColor: UIColor, alertColourIndex: Int) {

    self.alertCounter = alertCounter
    self.alertText = alertText
    self.alertColor = alertColor
    self.alertColorIndex = alertColourIndex
}

public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    alertCounter = aDecoder.decodeDoubleForKey("Item1")
    alertText = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Item2") as? String
    alertColor = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Item3") as? UIColor
    alertColorIndex = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("Item4")
}

public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    alertCounter = aCoder.decodeDoubleForKey("Item1")
    alertText = aCoder.decodeObjectForKey("Item2") as? String
    alertColor = aCoder.decodeObjectForKey("Item3") as? UIColor
    alertColorIndex = aCoder.decodeIntegerForKey("Item4")
}
}
```

The array (becomes populated when i add alert data in the app):

```
var alertDataSource: [alertData] = []
```

And to encode it:

```
let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.alertDataSource)
            print(archive)
```

And to extract it:

```
let result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archive)
            print(result)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips / advice

Comment: Also, alertArray is an array of alertData - there are multiple alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not meant to call `encodeWithCoder()` yourself. Use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. The `init(coder:)` and `encodeWithCoder()` will be called as needed by the archiver / unarchiver.

Place your `NSCoding`-compliant `alertData` instances (this should really be `AlertData` since class names should be proper case) into an array (or dictionary if you please) and do this:

```
let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourArrayOfAlertData)
```

In this case, `archive` will be an `NSData` instance.

**Update**

Actually, I guess I missed it the first time, but your `encode...()` method isn't right. At all. Consider the difference with:

```
public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeDouble(alertCounter, forKey:"Item1")
    aCoder.encodeObject(alertText, forKey:"Item2")
    aCoder.encodeObject(alertColor , forKey:"Item3")
    aCoder.encodeInteger(alertColorIndex, forKey:"Item4")
}
```

(Also consider naming your keys the same as their properties, like `"alertCounter"` for `alertCounter`.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply and information, my array of alert data looks like this     var alertDataSource: [alertData?] = [] but it is populated with alertData, when i try to call let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(alertDataSource) i have the error [alertData?] does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject", any ideas?

Comment: When you initially unarchive it you're going to get an array of AnyObject. That's because NSArray has to remain a "generic object array" to work with the rest of Cocoa and an NSArray is what you get back from the archiver. It's up to you to cast it to a more specific type.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out - im using

                let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.alertDataSource)
                print(archive)
                
                let result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archive)
                print(result)

And i get error:
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -decodeDoubleForKey: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSKeyedArchiver decodeDoubleForKey:]!'

Comment: Hi Joshua, i've added in what i want to do, i think saving it to the plist won't be an issue once i've managed to encode and decode it, thanks for the help, i've been stuck on this for ages