# Persist an array of custom structs in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, nsuserdefaults, persist

I'm trying to store an array of custom structs.

In my attempt below I get a run-time error in the second line of saveSampleArrayOfQuerySettings() complaining about casting to AnyObject.

```
struct QuerySettings {

    //    let ARRAY_INDEX_WHERE_TO_SAVE_STRUCT = 0

    let QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY = "querysettings"
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    private var _includeCompletedReminders: Bool = false        // Default value
    var includeCompletedReminders: Bool {
        get {
            // If value has been set before then use it otherwise retrieve it.
            return _includeCompletedReminders
        } set (newVal) {
            _includeCompletedReminders = newVal
            //            saveSettings(self, index: ARRAY_INDEX_WHERE_TO_SAVE_STRUCT, saveKey: QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY)
        }
    }

    private var _includeRemindersWithNoDueDate: Bool = true
    var includeRemindersWithNoDueDate: Bool {
        get {
            return _includeRemindersWithNoDueDate
        } set (newVal) {
            _includeRemindersWithNoDueDate = newVal
            //            saveSettings(self, index: ARRAY_INDEX_WHERE_TO_SAVE_STRUCT, saveKey: QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY)
        }
    }
}

func saveSampleArrayOfQuerySettings(saveKey: String) {
    let sampleArray = [QuerySettings(), QuerySettings()]

    // Persist
    let archivedSettingsArray = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(sampleArray as! AnyObject)

    // RUNTIME ERROR AT PREVIOUS LINE: "Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<RemindersPro.QuerySettings>' (0x112df10d8) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x1169d6018)."

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(archivedSettingsArray, forKey: saveKey)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    // For Testing Purposes - Load the saved settings
    if let retrievedArchivedSettingsArray : AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(saveKey) {
        if let settingsArray : AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(retrievedArchivedSettingsArray as! NSData) {
            let arr = settingsArray as! [QuerySettings]
            print(arr.first)
        }
    }
}

saveSampleArrayOfQuerySettings("saveKey")
```

I wonder whether I need to encode my struct. I checked out these posts but oddly couldn't even get the samples in the posts working (let alone applying them to my code.)

[How to save an array of objects to NSUserDefault with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240848/how-to-save-an-array-of-objects-to-nsuserdefault-with-swift)

[(Swift) Storing and retrieving Array to NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118735/swift-storing-and-retrieving-array-to-nsuserdefaults)

[How to save an array of custom structs to plist swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637377/how-to-save-an-array-of-custom-structs-to-plist-swift)

Can you please let me know how to get this working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays/33194374?s=2|0.0583#33194374

Comment: You will need to make a class NSCoding compliant and save it as NSData

Answer (score 4):

Your code is too verbose:

1. You don't need to explicit define type. Assign a default value of `true` or `false` is enough for the compiler to deduce that you want `Bool`. Swift is built around the idea that the compiler can be made very smart to lighten the on the programmer.
2. Your custom getters and setters do nothing special so it's best to let Swift auto-synthesize it.

Now, on to the topic of archiving: you will be dismayed to learn that `NSCoding` is only available to object which inherits from `NSObject`. Structs can not be made to conform to `NSCoding`. You need to wrap it around in a helper class.

---

Here's what I came up with:

### 1. Define a helper class to serialize structs:

```
protocol ArchivableStruct {
    var dataDictionary: [String: AnyObject] { get }
    init(dataDictionary aDict: [String: AnyObject])
}

class StructArchiver<T: ArchivableStruct>: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var structValue: T

    init(structValue: T) {
        self.structValue = structValue
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.structValue.dataDictionary, forKey: "dataDictionary")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let dataDictionary = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("dataDictionary") as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.structValue = T(dataDictionary: dataDictionary)
    }
}
```

### 2. Export data from the struct into a Dictionary

The dictionary is what gets archived. On the way back, we simply unpack this Dictionary to get the struct. We don't need to worry about `QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY` and `defaults` because the former is a constant and the later has its own data source (`NSUserDefaults`).

```
struct QuerySettings: ArchivableStruct {
    let QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY = "querysettings"
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var includeCompletedReminders = false
    var includeRemindersWithNoDueDate = true

    init(includeCompletedReminders: Bool, includeRemindersWithNoDueDate: Bool) {
        self.includeCompletedReminders = includeCompletedReminders
        self.includeRemindersWithNoDueDate = includeRemindersWithNoDueDate
    }

    // --------------------------------------
    // ArchivableStruct protocol
    // --------------------------------------
    var dataDictionary: [String: AnyObject] {
        get {
            return [
                "includeCompletedReminders": self.includeCompletedReminders,
                "includeRemindersWithNoDueDate": self.includeRemindersWithNoDueDate
            ]
        }
    }

    init(dataDictionary aDict: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.includeCompletedReminders = aDict["includeCompletedReminders"] as! Bool
        self.includeRemindersWithNoDueDate = aDict["includeRemindersWithNoDueDate"] as! Bool
    }
}
```

### 3. Mapping from `struct` to the helper class

Since you are not archiving a `QuerySetting` struct but an array of them, there is an extra step to map it to `StructArchiver<T>` so that your array can be archived:

```
// Set up a sample array
let a = QuerySettings(includeCompletedReminders: true, includeRemindersWithNoDueDate: false)
let b = QuerySettings(includeCompletedReminders: false, includeRemindersWithNoDueDate: true)
let sampleArray = [a, b]

// Archive
let wrapperArray = sampleArray.map { StructArchiver(structValue: $0) }
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(wrapperArray)

// Unarchive
let unwrapperArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! [StructArchiver<QuerySettings>]
let unarchivedArray = unwrapperArray.map { $0.structValue }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! (The code seems verbose, because I commented out the saveSettings() call - Whenever I change the var it is automatically persisted.) However, I decided to make my struct a class. Just seems less convoluted solution.

I am disappointed that structs seem to be second-class citizens to classes. (No pun intended.) Although the core language supports it, it seems that the framework does want you to go a different direction-classes, protocols, etc. I'd like to follow a functional programming style which prefers structs.It feels like like swimming against the flow...

Comment: @Daniel `NSCoder` is very old and thus deeply rooted in ObjC. `struct` in  C and ObjC are much less powerful than they are in Swift. Apple has a huge task of update the Cocoa library to keep up with Swift features. On the side though, `NSCoder` does support some structs some structs such as `CGPoint` and `CGSize`